# Анализ связей между таблицами и вставка данных в Access

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, access

Допустим я имею N-ое количество Access баз, которые схожи по структурам.

Эти N баз я должен объединить в одну, но есть проблема:

Так как таблицы взаимосвязаны внешними ключами, то как мне определить в какой последовательности я должен вставлять данные?

Можно ли обойтись без юзера, который явно укажет порядок работы с таблицами?

Есть конечно вариант убрать все связи и вставлять все подряд, но есть вероятность, что первичные ключи могут пересекаться => в конце получится каша...

Comment: Вероятно, можно использовать системные таблицы для работы с метаданными.

Comment: Для анализа связей вам может помочь моя старая утилита BatchAccess -- https://rsdn.ru/article/files/progs/BatchAccess.xml -- ей можно вытянуть всю структуру базы -- в том случае если база формата .mdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полноценных системных таблиц в Access нет. Но у соединения есть метод [`GetOleDbSchemaTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable(v=vs.110).aspx), через который можно получить всю схему базы, включая список таблиц и внешних ключей. После этого остается только отсортировать из в нужном порядке, так чтобы зависимые таблицы шли после тех, от которых они зависят. Примерно так:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\temp\Database2.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
var tables = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[0])
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(t => t.Field<string>("TABLE_TYPE") == "TABLE")
    .Select(t => t.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME"))
    .ToList();

var foreignKeys = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Foreign_Keys, new object[0])
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(t => new
    {
        PKTable = t.Field<string>("PK_TABLE_NAME"),
        FKTable = t.Field<string>("FK_TABLE_NAME")
    })
    .ToList();

var tablesToCopy = new List<string>();

var tablesWithResolvedFKs = new List<string>();
do
{
    // отфильтровать FK, оставить только ссылающиеся на оставшиеся таблицы
    foreignKeys = foreignKeys.Where(fk => tables.Contains(fk.PKTable)).ToList();

    // выбрать те таблицы, которые не зависят от других оставшихся
    List<string> tablesWithUnresolvedFKs = foreignKeys.Select(fk => fk.FKTable).ToList();
    tablesWithResolvedFKs = tables.Except(tablesWithUnresolvedFKs).ToList();

    tablesToCopy.AddRange(tablesWithResolvedFKs);

    tables = tables.Except(tablesWithResolvedFKs).ToList();
} while (tablesWithResolvedFKs.Any());

// результат - в tablesToCopy
```