# записать в массив имена столбцов таблицы БД (access) с#

Tags: c#, access

Как записать в массив имена столбцов таблицы БД (access)?

Код подключения:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"+ @"Data Source= C:\Users\Person.accdb");
```

Comment: что вы используете для подключения к базе данных?

Comment: string[] arrDBColName = new string[] { "имя 1", "имя 2", "имя 3", "имя 4", "имя 5", "имя 6" };

Comment: Подключаюсь так:

Comment: OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"+
                @"Data Source= C:\Users\Person.accdb");

Comment: @Наталья, отредактируйте вопрос, добавив в него весь необходимый код

Comment: @Наталья, Имена столбцов какой именно таблицы, базы данных `Person`, вы хотите записать в массив

Comment: в этой базе есть таблица students

Comment: @Наталья в access можно достать схему базы вызовом GetOleDbSchemaTable - посмотрите http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456517/177221. Если по ссылке достаточно информации для решения - скажите, я отмечу вопрос как дубликат. Если нет - может быть кто-то запостит сюда полноценный ответ

Comment: @LamerXaKer насколько я понял, это задача - зная имя таблицы в базе, узнать имена ее колонок, кодом

Comment: Вот тут все подробно указано [ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857942/how-can-i-get-the-field-names-of-a-database-table)

Comment: @YuriiManziuk, Я бы сказал, что указано подробно, всё же тут [SoEN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775047/fetch-column-names-for-specific-table)

Comment: @YuriiManziuk это решение не работает в Access, о чем и сказано по ссылке

Comment: @YuriiManziuk, в ответе по ссылке речь про mssql, а в текущем вопросе про access

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication52
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"Data Source= C:\Users\Person.accdb"))
            {
                con.Open();
                string [] columns = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, null)
                                        .AsEnumerable()
                                        .Where(r => r.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME") == "Students")
                                        .Select(r => r.Field<string>("COLUMN_NAME"))
                                        .ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все работает!